# Avoid slow for loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to avoid slow for loops in MATLAB. I have RGB image and i'm trying to calculate mahalanobis distance manually. Here is example code about mahalanobis distance function which works with for loops:

```
H = 10;
W = 20;
im = rand(H,W,3);
Mean = rand(1,3);
SigmaInv = rand(3,3);   
[size1, size2, size3] = size(im);
imDistance = zeros(size1,size2);
for i = 1:size1
    for j = 1:size2
        x(:,:) = (im(i,j,:));
        x1 = transpose(x);
        imDistance(i,j) = sqrt((x1-Mean)*SigmaInv*transpose(x1-Mean));
    end
end
```

im dimensions are [HxWx3], Mean dimensions are [1x3], SignaInv [3x3] and output imDistance should be [HxW]. I think that code will be faster if I use bsxfun and permute functions but I can't figure out how to implement it. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48682844/edit) your question and add a few statements to make this code work on it's own? Perhaps a couple of `H=10; W=20; im = rand(H,W,3);` statements. Plus your line `imDistance(i,j)` has an expression `xl'modelMean` which I think is a typo.

Comment: Now the code is edited and hopefully the problem is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty simple using the [reshape function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
H = 10;
W = 20;
im = rand(H,W,3);
Mean = rand(1,3);
SigmaInv = rand(3,3);   
[size1, size2, size3] = size(im);

sm = SigmaInv * transpose(Mean);

im_flat = reshape(im,size1*size2,3);
calc = sqrt((im_flat - Mean) * sm);
imDistance = reshape(calc,size1,size2);
```

Comment: This works very well but now my problem is following : "Requested 307200x307200 (703.1GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit
may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more
information." This is probably because of too big image but is there any other way to avoid this memory error?

Comment: Wow... that's a huge one! I'm not expert about this, but you should read this https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/large-files-and-big-data.html. Maybe it's a good starting point.

Comment: That's probably because I had typo in first version of code and I corrected the line "imDistance(i,j) = sqrt((x1-Mean)*SigmaInv*transpose(x1-Mean));" and now this technique doesn't work. I have to figure out how to do it differently.